# Using pointers references

Tags: c++, pointers

I need use a var from pointer reference in another function, so, when I call that I pass the address value, but how can I use this pointer there (not creating another instance)?
Look the code segment:

```
//Main region - using Product class -> _products = vector<Product>
int main()
{
    _products.reserve(2);
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        productRefe.SetProduct(&_products);
    return 0;
}


//Method in Product.cpp
void Product::SetProduct(vector<Product> *productsP)
{
    vector<Product> products = *productsP;
    Product productInsert;
    cout << "Type the description: ";
    cin >> productInsert.Struct.description;
        products.push_back(productInsert);
}

  void Product::GetProducts(string description, bool all, vector<Product> *productsP)
  {
int i = 0;
vector<Product> products = *productsP;
if(all)
    for(i = 0; i < products.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Description: " << products[i].Struct.description << endl;
        cout << "Value" << products[i].Struct.value << endl << endl;
            }
   }
```

I believe the problem is in the first line in method SetProduct... But, what can I change to it works?
Thanks

Comment: Be aware that "reference" has a significant meaning in C++, and your question/code does not use it this way. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above alternatives are better, but this would work also (local variable is a reference):
`vector<Product> &products = *productsP;`

Answer (score 1):

Suggested alternatives:

```
// Declare a reference in your signature (instead of a pointer)
void Product::SetProduct(vector<Product>& products)
{
    Product productInsert;
    cout << "Type the description: ";
    cin >> productInsert.Struct.description;
        products.push_back(productInsert);
}
```

... or ...

```
void Product::SetProduct(vector<Product> *productsP)
{
    Product productInsert;
    cout << "Type the description: ";
    // Declare a pointer ... and simply use the pointer as a pointer
    cin >> productInsert.Struct.description;
        products->push_back(productInsert);
}
```

In neither case do you need or want "products" - it's extraneous. Just use the variable you passed in.

IMHO ... and I hope that helps...

Comment: Yes, sounds good... but I need to get index by index on function GetProducts, and I cant do it with pointer reference (I think)

Comment: It should also be noted that: "vector<Product> products = *productsP" copies the contents pointed to by productsP into products, and subsequently productsP never gets updated.

Comment: @MGE if you use a reference for GetProducts as well, you can use the subscript operator as usual. I.e. cout << products[i].

Answer (score 1):

Your code is adding a new product to a vector and then destroying the new vector almost immediately.

```
void Product::SetProduct(vector<Product> *productsP)
{
    vector<Product> products = *productsP; // creates a new vector<Product> and copies the vector pointed to by ProductsP into it
    Product productInsert;
    cout << "Type the description: ";
    cin >> productInsert.Struct.description;
        products.push_back(productInsert); // adds the new product to the new vector<Product>
    // as this function exits, products goes out of scope and is destroyed, so no change is ever saved
}
```

In addition to the other solutions which can fix this problem, I would suggest making the vector a member of a collection class:

```
class Products
{
// other members/functions
public:
    void AddProduct(const Product& prod)
    {
        m_Products.push_back(prod);
    }
private:
    std::vector<Product> m_Products;
};
```

Or, just using the collection itself.  What you have posted would lead me to believe you are mixing concerns in your class.

Comment: That's another good way, thanks, but I'm using the @Jason solution **vector<Product> &products = *productsP;**

Answer (score 0):

In the function, don't make a copy, but use `*productsP` directly, for example:

```
cin >> productsP->Struct.description;
```

Comment: Sorry... but productsP's a vector of Product